# How to modify an object by its property reference?

Tags: javascript, reflection

I want to be able to increment the property of an object by having the reference of the property itself, but not the reference of the object itself.

I am sure this could be achievable through some sort of reflection, but not really familiar with the available resources in JavaScript to  achieve so.

Sample code:

```
let myObject = {
  a: 1
}

// reference of my object property
let target = myObject.a

let test = (destination) => {

  // increment
  destination += 1 
   
  
}

test(target);
// prints {a: 1} - Does not work
console.log(myObject);
```

The following does not work because we are trying to modify the reference of the direct integer property, which is mutable aswell. `destination` would equal to 2, but the parent object `myObject` stays unchanged. Is there anyway to achieve, through reflection, alteration of `myObject` by just having the reference of one of its property, if we consider that a case whereas `myObject` would be **outside of the function's scope**?

Comment: can't `let d = myObject; d.a++` be an option?

Comment: As the question states at the ending.... " if we consider that a case whereas myObject would be out of the function's scope". That is exactly what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You can declare `d` and increment `d.a` outside the function.

Comment: _"by having the reference of the property "_. There are no references to primitive types.

Comment: @ThomasSablik so the only way would be passing to the scope the reference to the master object, and therefore passing the path all the way to the property I'm targeting?

Comment: You don't need the master object but you need the parent object. In your case it's the same.

Comment: @ThomasSablik clear enough. Therefore my function to properly work would need the following parameters: ({ targetObject: object, targetKey: string })